# Genymotion old version download

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I saw that starting at a version after 1.3.1, Genymotion stopped supporting Gapps and ARM support.

I would like to know if anyone has a link to a 64/32 bit MAC version of GenyMotion V1.3.1 or earlier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U don't wanna the old version of Genymotion.
The new version of Genymotion is based on the x86 system, it won't support AR anymore(and so as the Gapps).
So just add the arm support:
Check [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952), download the Genymotion_ARM_tranlation_v11.zip,install it on your genymotion,restart, and done.

Comment: "The new version of Genymotion is based on the x86 system, it won't support AR anymore(and so as the Gapps)." I know thats why I want the old version. And I already saw that solution but the problem is you need to do it to every device you try and its a big waste of time.